# Store slider value in view to global variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, audiokit

I have several views nested within each other in my Swift program. In the lowest level view, I have a slider. I'd like to pass it's value from this view to the main Swift file where the global variable is stored within a struct. This value will be used to control the volume of the audio being played using AudioKit.

Code for slider (not included the full view here as the rest is irrelevant):

```
struct MasterFaderView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Slider(
            value: master.Value,
            in: 0...127,
            step: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Top Level global variable being set:

```
struct channel {
    var Value: Double = 0.0             // Default fader value
    ... // Other variables being stored
}

var master = channel()

@main
struct MEngProjectApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FreePlayView()
        }
    }
}
```

FreePlayView() is the main view which contains the audioKit stuff and will control the volume:

```
class MixerClass: ObservableObject {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var fullTrack = AudioPlayer()
    
    init() {
        engine.output = fullTrack
        loadFiles()
        try? engine.start()
    }
    
    func loadFiles() {
        do {
            if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DQ_FullTrack", withExtension: "wav") {
                try fullTrack.load(url: fileURL)
            } else {
                Log("Could not find file")
            }
        } catch {
            Log("Could not load full track")
        }
    }
}

struct FreePlayView: View {
    @StateObject var conductor = MixerClass()
    @State var trackPlaying: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
        if trackPlaying == false {
            conductor.fullTrack.start()
            conductor.fullTrack.volume = master.Value
            trackPlaying = true
        } else {
            conductor.fullTrack.stop()
            trackPlaying = false
        }
   }) {
      Text("Start Audio")
   }
```

The error code I get within MasterFaderView is
`Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Binding<Double>'`

Anyone any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A global variable like this is likely not a good solution. You may want to read about "EnvironmentObject" for something that is _similar_.

Comment: Globals don’t have the ability to tell SwiftUI to reload views, also generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wpitchy,

In your code snippets, I'm not seeing where you're updating the `fullTrack.volume` via the Slider's value.

I would also keep the `@Published var fullTrackVolume` variable in the `Conductor`, instead of in its own `ChannelMode` class, because it affects the `fullTrack` AudioPlayer that was instantiated there.

Here's what I would change:

**MEngProjectApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MEngProjectApp: App {

    // If you want the MixerClass to be available in multiple views (not just FreePlayView), you will want to instantiate it as an EnvironmentObject in the App level.
    @StateObject var conductor = MixerClass()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FreePlayView()
                .environmentObject(conductor) // <- Passing this object into this parent view will allow the MixerClass to be accessible from the FreePlayView and any of its child views.
        }
    }
}
```

**MixerClass.swift**

```
import AudioKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

final class MixerClass: ObservableObject {

    let engine = AudioEngine()

    @Published var fullTrack = AudioPlayer() // <- Published vars broadcast any updates that occur, such as volume level changes.
    @Published var isTrackPlaying: Bool = false

    init() {

        // Importing AVFoundation is required in order to access the AVAudioSession settings.
        do {
            Settings.bufferLength = .medium
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredIOBufferDuration(Settings.bufferLength.duration)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                                                            options: [.defaultToSpeaker,
                                                                      .mixWithOthers,
                                                                      .allowBluetoothA2DP])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

        loadFiles()
        fullTrack.isLooping = true // <- Set this to true, if you don't want the audio clip to stop playing.
        engine.output = fullTrack
        try? engine.start()
    }

    func loadFiles() {
        do {
            if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "DQ_FullTrack", withExtension: "wav") {
                try fullTrack.load(url: fileURL)
            } else {
                Log("Could not find file")
            }
        } catch {
            Log("Could not load full track")
        }
    }

    func convertVolumeToPercent() -> String {
        "\(Int(fullTrack.volume * 100))%" // <- Converts 0.5 to 50% and 1.0 to 100%, etc.
    }

    // MARK: User Intent Actions from any or multiple views.
    // This way, the business logic "decision-making" from triggered events will remain outside of any of the views. These actions can be repurposed, and not tied to any view code.

    func playStopToggle() {
        isTrackPlaying ? fullTrack.stop() : fullTrack.start()
        isTrackPlaying.toggle()
    }
}
```

**FreePlayView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FreePlayView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var conductor: MixerClass

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MasterFaderView()
            playStopButton
        }
    }

    private var playStopButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            conductor.playStopToggle()
        }) {
            Text("\(Image(systemName: conductor.isTrackPlaying ? "stop.fill" : "play.fill")) \(conductor.isTrackPlaying ? "Stop" : "Start") Audio")
        }
    }
}

struct FreePlayView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FreePlayView()
            .environmentObject(MixerClass()) // <- Pass in the MixerClass in order for the SwiftUI Preview to work without crashing.
    }
}
```

**MasterFaderView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct MasterFaderView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var conductor: MixerClass

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(conductor.convertVolumeToPercent())
                .font(.title).fontWeight(.thin)
            Slider(value: $conductor.fullTrack.volume, in: 0...1) // <- Volume in the AudioPlayer is 0.0-1.0, not 0-127.
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct MasterFaderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MasterFaderView()
            .environmentObject(MixerClass()) // <- Pass in the MixerClass in order for the SwiftUI Preview to work without crashing.
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

If you'd like to see this in a larger Xcode project, please check out the following:

https://github.com/markjeschke/AKVolumeControl

Comment: Thank you so much, that has worked absolutely beautifully and your project really helped as well!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped! I wish you the best with your project!

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in various places in your App, you can use an `ObservableObject` class,
with a `@Published var value: Double = 0.0` as shown in `class ChannelModel: ObservableObject`.
Whenever the `value` changes, the UI will refresh.

Declare this `ChannelModel` in your App, and
pass it around using `.environmentObject(channelModel)` and
`@EnvironmentObject var channel: ChannelModel` as shown in
`FreePlayView` and `MasterFaderView`.

Here is some example code for this approach:

```
@main
struct MEngProjectApp: App {
    @StateObject var channelModel = ChannelModel() // <-- here

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FreePlayView()
                .environmentObject(channelModel)  // <-- here
        }
    }
}

class ChannelModel: ObservableObject {  // <-- here
    @Published var value: Double = 0.0  // <-- here
    // ... Other variables being stored
}

struct FreePlayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var channelModel: ChannelModel  // <-- here
    
    @StateObject var conductor = MixerClass()
    @State var trackPlaying: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if trackPlaying == false {
                conductor.fullTrack.start()
                conductor.fullTrack.volume = channelModel.value  // <-- here
                trackPlaying = true
            } else {
                conductor.fullTrack.stop()
                trackPlaying = false
            }
        }) {
            Text("Start Audio")
        }
    }
}

struct MasterFaderView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var channelModel: ChannelModel  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $channelModel.value, in: 0...127, step: 1.0)  // <-- here
    }
}
```

Comment: this does change the value being stored but doesn't regularly update to make it responsive. The slider is supposed to change the volume in real time but it only changes it once the conductor is stopped and restarted. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: You declare `class MixerClass: ObservableObject` but you are not publishing anything.
Although you don't show what `AudioPlayer` is, you could try `@Published var fullTrack = AudioPlayer()`.
 
 Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app
 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)  Note, it is not recommended to **nest** ObservableObjects.